How Do I Pass Streaming Data from Nitro API to Pinia Store so I can use it in Nuxt Component?
In my Nuxt app I have a Pinia store and am making an API call via the Nitro server that gets streaming data in response. When I try to update the Pinia store with the streaming data it does not update, i.e. I can call
const streamOutput = ref({ value: "", annotations: [] })
const setStreamOutput = (output) => {
    console.log("setStreamOutput", output)
    streamOutput.value = output
    console.log("setStreamOutput", output)
}

and will see the console log but in my server logs, not in Browser and in my template and in the browser tool I still see the initial value for streamOutput.
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    const body = await readBody(event)
    const chatStore = useChatStore()
    const readable = new Readable({
        read() {} // No-op implementation for read method
    })

    const run = sendStream(
        event,
        await openai.beta.threads
            .createAndRunStream({
                assistant_id: *ID*,
                thread: {
                    messages: [
                        { role: "user", content: "Explain deep learning to a 5 year old." }
                    ]
                }
            })
            .on("messageCreated", async (text) => {
                console.log("\n\n messageCreated", text)
            })
            .on("textDelta", async (textDelta, snapshot) => {
                console.log("\n\n textDelta", snapshot)
                await chatStore.setStreamOutput(snapshot)
            })
            .on("toolCallCreated", async (toolCall) => {
                console.log("\n\n toolCallCreated", toolCall)
            })
            .on("toolCallDelta", async (toolCallDelta, snapshot) => {
                console.log("\n\n toolCallDelta", snapshot)
                if (toolCallDelta.type === "code_interpreter") {
                    if (toolCallDelta.code_interpreter.input) {
                        chatStore.setStreamOutput(
                            chatStore.streamOutput + toolCallDelta.code_interpreter.input
                        )
                    }
                    if (toolCallDelta.code_interpreter.outputs) {
                        chatStore.setStreamOutput(chatStore.streamOutput + "\noutput >\n")
                        toolCallDelta.code_interpreter.outputs.forEach((output) => {
                            if (output.type === "logs") {
                                chatStore.setStreamOutput(
                                    chatStore.streamOutput + `\n${output.logs}\n`
                                )
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
            .on("textDone", async (content, snapshot) => {
                console.log("\n\n text Done")
            })
    )

    return sendStream(event, readable)
})


The question lacks a clear problem statement and a way to reproduce. It's unknown why it doesn't update or whether you correctly determine this. Currently only you can debug this. If chatStore.setStreamOutput is called, it's called. It's also unclear if this happens on server or client side

For anyone running into this the solution has two parts:

Creating and returning a Readable
Updating your Pinia store to read the data stream

For creating a Readable
import { Readable } from "stream"
import { sendStream } from "h3"

const readable = new Readable({
        read() {} // No-op implementation for read method
    })
await openai.beta.threads
        .createAndRunStream({
            ...
        })
        .on("messageCreated", async (text) => {
            readable.push(`{"messageCreated": ${JSON.stringify(text)}}\n`)
        })
//Handle other events similarly
...
return sendStream(event, readable)
})

For updating your Pinia store to read the data stream
(This is a bit tedious and I'm sure it can be optimized but I will forget about this answer in a bit and figure I should post before that)
const streamOutput = ref({ value: "", annotations: [] })

const setStreamOutput = (output) => {
    streamOutput.value = output
}

const createRun = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/run/create", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                threadId: thread.value.id
            })
        })

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok")
        }

        const reader = response.body.getReader()
        const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8")

        let buffer = ""

        let done = false
        while (!done) {
            const { value, done: readerDone } = await reader.read()
            done = readerDone
            if (value) {
                buffer += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true })

                // Process complete JSON objects in the buffer
                let boundary
                while ((boundary = buffer.indexOf("\n")) !== -1) {
                    const chunk = buffer.slice(0, boundary).trim()
                    buffer = buffer.slice(boundary + 1)

                    if (chunk) {
                        try {
                            const json = JSON.parse(chunk)
                            if (json.textDelta) {
                                // VVVVV Here you can hook into your store's function to use the data
                                setStreamOutput(json.textDelta.value)
                            } else if (json.messageCreated) {
                                ... // Handle other streaming events
                                

